# php passing session information to the model via functions vs. allowing model to grab an instance of the session data and get what it needs

Tags: php, model-view-controller, session

does anyone know what the php best practices on session information is? should the model request access to the global session variable and then select the information it needs, or should the methods of the model accept the session information as parameters and let the controller handle grabbing the data from the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since models contain your business logic, they should be as independent as possible from anything else. E.g. you might want to access your business logic in a context without sessions, from the command line for example.

As such, models should explicitly be passed any and all data they need to work on.